# Store Combobox items in The Form of Array and Retrieve SelectedId in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, combobox

I am a c++ developer and recently shifted to this amazing WPF world. I am developing a WPF application. I have a combobox (BusRate) in my xaml file.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding BusRateList}" SelectedIndex="2" Name="comboBox2" Width="85" />
```

My Viewmodel class has the following property:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> _busRate = new ObservableCollection<int>();
public ObservableCollection<int> BusRateList
    {
        get { return _busRate; }
        set
        {
            _busRate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BusRateList");
        }
    }
```

And I add the items as follows:

```
_busRate.Add(10);
_busRate.Add(50);
_busRate.Add(100);
_busRate.Add(200);
_busRate.Add(300);
_busRate.Add(400);
_busRate.Add(500);
_busRate.Add(600);
```

This gives me the items in my combobox. But I want to add these items into my combobox in the form of a array which holds all these values. E.g.:

```
// C++ Code
static const char *busRate[8] = 
{
" 10", " 50", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600"
};
```

thus allowing me to perform the following operation oncomboboxitemselected method:

- Get the SelectedId from the Combobox and store it in a integer variable.
- pass this integer varaible. Demonstration as follows:

  ```
  int id = comboBox->getSelectedId(); // C++ Code
  unsigned long speed = String(busRate[id-1]).getIntValue(); // C++ Code
  ```

How can I achieve this in my application :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new property in your ViewModel of type int and a [converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) which converts a string to an int value. Now you bind the new property to the ComboBox.SelectedItem-property:

```
<Window/UserControl/....Resouces>
    <local:YourConverter x:Key="TheConverter"/>
<Window/UserControl/....Resouces>

<ComboBox SelectedIten="{Binding Path=IntProp, Converter={StaticResource TheConverter}}"
```

EDIT:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(BusRateList[comboBox.SelectedIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't it possible to perform the operation using a simple array method??? If u notice the two points towards the end, these lines in c++ play an important role in my class. I just want to keep things simple. Is their a way to do it like this?

Comment: Wow thats awesome :) This clears my first hurdle. What about the second one??? How do I get the  busrate[id-1] and IntValue and store it in a unsignedLong as mentioned in my second point :) Since I am not using Array, now will it be possible for me to use busrate[id-1]???

Comment: it is possible, but not necessary. You can bind the selected item to a property in your viewmodel and convert this into a string. alternative: var index = _busRate.IndexOf(_selectedItem);
            var value = _busRate[index].ToString();